# Bootstrap Angular 5 mobile row not inline

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

How can I adjust the row to be inline when less than 579px wide?
I need it to be the same on the mobile as on the desktop.

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css"
  ],
```

```html
<div class="card-body text-left">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5  col-lg-5">
        {{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1  col-lg-1 ">
        <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{address}}" target="_blank">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker" title="{{address}}"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1  col-lg-1 ">
        <a href="tel:{{contact.phoneNumber}}">
          <i class="fa fa-phone" title="{{contact.phoneNumber}}">
          </i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1  col-lg-1 ">
        <a href="mailto:{{contact.email}}">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope" title="{{contact.email}}">
          </i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2  col-lg-2 ">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1  col-lg-1 ">
        <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="edit(contact)">
          <i class="fa fa-edit left"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1  col-lg-1 ">
        <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="delete(contact)">
          <i class="fa fa-trash left"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

> Update
>   As suggested in all comments changed to the col-1 pattern
>   As you can see bellow still the same
>   [image]

You can see that the upper part set with col-1 pattern and the one on the bottom with previous configuration.

All that leads me to believe that somehow I need to adjust the reference to the css somewhere in my Angular-CLI project.
Now as I use Material Design and MDBootstrap that has to give me a support for responsiveness it is weird it doesn't..

> package.json

```
 "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.0.1",
```

In angular I don't think it's best practice just to put the css files in index.html.
I probably can npm install bootstrap package , but the question is will it override and mess up other frameworks - Material Design and MDBoostrap ?

I"ll try and update here..

> Update

npm install bootstrap

```
 "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
```

installed bootstrap 4 for angular-cli project
yet no effect on the code. 
:(

> Update

Worked after clearing cache and refreshing.Cool. Thank guys!

still would need to adjust for pc and mobile.. 
now it's just ugly(especially mobile) in any option but it's a good direction..
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The grid system changed from BS3 to BS4. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ for the latest reference.

Comment: @Fabian Schöner Yeah..I've used it to build the form

Comment: Yes but youre using the bootstrap4 stylesheets with the bootstrap3 grid system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Instead of using `col-xs-1`, use `col-1` (`xs` does not exsit in bootstrap-4)**

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jpfgtrc3/3/

**Actually you don't need the others (`col-md-1`...) only `col-1` :https://jsfiddle.net/jpfgtrc3/5/**

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card-body text-left">
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    your name
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{address}}" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker" title="{{address}}"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <a href="tel:{{contact.phoneNumber}}">
      <i class="fa fa-phone" title="{{contact.phoneNumber}}">
      </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <a href="mailto:{{contact.email}}">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope" title="{{contact.email}}">
      </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="edit(contact)">
      <i class="fa fa-edit left"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="delete(contact)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash left"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**To your update:**

Use `p-o` to `col-*` and  `d-none d-sm-block` to  `<div class="col-2">`

**See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jpfgtrc3/14/**

Comment: it doesn't work in both jsfiddles.. 
on both they scroll to two rows..
or maybe i didn't get it.. 
for me seems that switch to col-1 didn't do any difference

Comment: bootstrap 4 declare classes to spacinig (whats mean that you don't have to set css only bootstrap class) `p` means padding and `-0` mean `padding:0`.... Learn more here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: got it.. didn't know that syntax for bootstrap .. thanks.
I probably will need to create two options - one for pc and one for mobile .. it still doesn't play well. what do you think? can it be done - two in one?

Comment: why it's not good? and of course NO you don't have to create one to pc and one for mobile...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173866/discussion-between-tzvi-gregory-kaidanov-and--).

Comment: I agree that it's not the best practice.. at all..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use only class `col-1`, `col-4` , etc.. classes instead of using `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*` and `col-lg--*` classes

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    {{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 ">
    <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{address}}" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker" title="{{address}}"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 ">
    <a href="tel:{{contact.phoneNumber}}">
      <i class="fa fa-phone" title="{{contact.phoneNumber}}">
      </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <a href="mailto:{{contact.email}}">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope" title="{{contact.email}}">
      </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
  </div>

  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="primary" (click)="edit(contact)">
      <i class="fa fa-edit left"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="delete(contact)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash left"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```